# WPF window doesn't resize with the content of ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, resize, window, contentpresenter

There is a WPF window like this,

```
.
.
.
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CameraCanvas}" Focusable="true" Margin="0" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I want the parent window resized according to the `ContentPresenter` content. Content is loading dynamically

`SizeToContent` and `VerticalAlignment`/`HorizontalAlignment` didn't worked. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `SizeToContent` to `WidthAndHeight` should work. Note that the `SizeToContent` property is automatically set to `Manual` if a user resizes the window by using the resize grip or dragging the border though so you probably also want to set the `ResizeMode` property to `NoResize`.

Please refer to the following sample code which sets the `Content` property of the `ContentPresenter` to a 500x300 Rectangle after 3 seconds:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="cc" Focusable="true" Margin="0">
            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                <TextBlock>test</TextBlock>
            </ContentPresenter.Content>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += async (s, e) => 
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            cc.Content = new Rectangle { Width = 500, Height = 300, Fill = Brushes.Red };
        };
    }
}
```

The size of the window is then increased just as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Then you are obviously doing something wrong because it works wonders for me. What does "not work" actually mean?

Comment: It seems like window is open like empty content(like window width and height equals to 0). But content is there for sure.

Comment: I use following code to open the window,

CameraWindow myObject = null;
            try
            {
                myObject = (CameraWindow) (Activator.CreateInstance(ty));
myObject.DataContext = os;
myObject.ShowDialog();

Comment: Does the window size adjusts to the size of the content eventually?

Comment: No... window width = 0 height = 0. If  I could resize the window then I can see that the content is there. Problem is window doesn't resize according to it

Comment: So you didn't set the ResizeMode property then. Did you even try my sample code?

Comment: I did like you said. It didn't work. At that point I couldn't check whether the content is loaded or not. So I tried again changing ResizeMode property. At that point I saw content is there.

Comment: Did you create a new window and pasted in my sample code? It is not mine code that doesn't work. It yours. You should read this and modify your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your code is working. In my case I use,
Content="{Binding CameraCanvas}". I think that can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late, I was having the same issue and found a different solution -

Using the parent ContentControl as,

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentPresenter .../>
</ContentContro>
```